# About fundamental matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about fundamental matrices. Apparently, for systems of the form $x' = Ax$, the fundamental matrix is $\Phi(t) = \text{exp}(A t)$. But when we have a time-dependent matrix, $A(t)$, the book I have been reading says we may have, in certain cases, $\Phi(t) \neq \text{exp}\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}A(s)\,ds\right)$ ($A(t)$ is continuous here). I've been trying to find examples of that without success. Is there any condition on $A(t)$ that makes it simpler to generate such examples? Is there a trivial matrix $A(t)$ that I missed?

Comment: Not in certain cases, in almost all cases. You only retain the matrix-exponential form if all $A(t), A(s)$ commute.

Comment: I don't know if the matrix $A(t)=\left( \begin{array}{ll} 0&t\\ 0& 1  \end{array}  \right)$ can be considered trivial, but it suits your requirements